# SQL Job, Linked Server, Domain Account

Tags: linked-server, sql-job

I think I have tried everything but I can't figure out how to set up an SQL Job that have a T-SQL Step that performs a SELECT on a linked server.

1) I got a Domain user mydomain\SQLJob

2) I got a SQL 2017 server 'JOBSERVER' with the SQL Agent running log on as a domain user mydomain\sv_agent (this cannot be changed). No futher rights should be given to this user either.

3) On the JOBSERVER I created a linked server

```
 EXEC sp_addlinkedserver 'LINKEDSERVER'
```

4) mydomain\SQLJob is data reader on a database on LINKEDSERVER

5) I am able to do a SELECT * FROM LINKEDSERVER... from JOBSERVER in a regular Query Window.

On JOBSERVER I have tried

```
 ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase SET TRUSTWORTHY ON
```

And then set the job to execute in MyDatabase

I have also tried

```
 Job Step Properties > Advanced > Run as user > mydomain\SQLJob
```

I have tried adding mydomain\SQLJob to the linked server on JOBSERVER both with and without Impersonate

Could someone let me know what the correct steps are ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found another post that stated it could not be done.

What I did instead was changing the T-SQL to a PowerShell script. Here the Run As works just fine.